# How can we use multiple router outlets in Angular+Nativescript application?

Tags: angular, navigation, nativescript, nativescript-angular, router-outlet

I am working on Nativescript+Angular application and currenlty I have the requirement of multiple outlet in my application.

I want to use different-2 outlets for different components.

Here is my example code:

***app.component.html***

```html
<page-router-outlet name="login"></page-router-outlet>
<page-router-outlet name="register"></page-router-outlet>
```

***app-routing.module.ts***

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'login' },
  { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent, outlet: 'register' }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
```

I am getting blank screen with this code. If any one knows please let me know that how we can handle this.

Comment: try in **app.component.html** add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: You can not have multiple router outlets at root level. There should be only one element at root level, if you like multiple outlets you need a Layout or at least a TabView which can hold them.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to use router-outlet but it's very tricky do that ... I make it using as reference this [repo](https://github.com/ADjenkov/login-tabs-ng)

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for multiple router outlets in Angular+Nativescript.

**app-routing.module.ts:-**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NSEmptyOutletComponent } from "nativescript-angular";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "login",
    pathMatch: "full"
},
{
    path: "login",
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
    loadChildren: "~/app/login/login.module#LoginModule",
    outlet: "login"
},
{
    path: "register",
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
    loadChildren: "~/app/register/register.module#RegisterModule",
    outlet: "register"
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html:-**

```
<page-router-outlet name="login">
</page-router-outlet>

<page-router-outlet name="register">
</page-router-outlet>
```